# book title abbreviation in references

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm writing my PhD in philosophy with LaTeX (using TeXshop and Bibdesk on a Mac) and I have a question:

I use the work of one philosopher frequently, so I introduce a list of abbreviations in the beginning (for example: Being and Time would be BT). I have been using `\citetext` now for this (e.g. `\citetext{BT, 27}`), but I am not sure if this will be printed in the bibliography of the pdf file (BT is also the bibtex key).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a bit more information about (i) any packages you may be using to help with citations and references and (ii) the BibTeX (or biblatex?) bibliography style file (or files) you're using. Separately, have you already looked into using the `natbib` package and its `\defcitealias`, `\citetalias`, and `\citepalias` commands? (I gather the `\citetext` command is provided by the `apalike` or a related package, right?)

Comment: i am using natbib indeed. But I tried defcitealias and the other commands, and that does exactly what I need. Thanks for that!

Comment: I've expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take the following example entry:

```
@book{BT,
  author = "Martin Heidegger",
  title  = "Being and Time",
  year   = 1962,
  publisher = "Blackwell",
}
```

You mention in a comment that you use the `natbib` package. Assuming you employ an author-year citation style, the command `\citet{BT}` generates `Heidegger (1962)` as its output.

The command

```
\defcitealias{BT}{BT} % first arg: key; second arg: alias
```

serves to set up an alias for this entry. (Of course, the fact that the citation key and the alias are identical for this particular example is not exactly a coincidence.) Then, the command `\citetalias{BT}` will simply generate `BT`, and the command `\citepalias[see][p.~25]{BT}` will generate `(see BT, p. 25)`. Note that the commands `\citetalias` and `\citepalias` work exactly like the "ordinary" `\citet` and `\citep` commands -- except, of course, that they'll place the designated alias in the appropriate spot.